# How can I output all results of a while loop as a string?

Tags: php, mysql

I am wanting to pull data from MySQL and create a string with all the data pulled in a string as 1 variable.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{

$x= $row['SessionValue'];

}
```

I know that this is miles away from what I am after but if the data pulled is: a,b,c,d (commas representing each loop) my desired output would be:

```
$x='<li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li><li>d</li>'
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just chain it in a variable

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{

     $x= $x."<li>".$row['SessionValue']."</li>";

}
```

Comment: or $x .= '<li>'.$row['SessionValue'].'</li>';

Comment: That's right. But I believe it's more clear the usual chaining method for newbies :)

Comment: I used $x .= '<li>'.$row['SessionValue'].'</li>' first but when I used $x outside the loop it only contained the last value pulled (<li>d</li> in my example) :/

Comment: @MichaelJones better try with my example, then. That should work well. ^-^

Comment: Thanks it looks promising I will report on its success later :)